# Nested json jbuilder for photo feed having n+1 major issues

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having performance issues on one of my api views so I ran the Bullet gem and found some major N+1 issues with the view.

The api is being consumed so the format has to remain identical.

Bullet N+1 output:

> localhost:3000/api/v1/games/1/game_feed N+1 Query detected
>   CompletedQuest => [:comments]   Add to your finder: :include =>
>   [:comments] N+1 Query method call stack
>   /app/views/api/v1/games/game_feed.json.jbuilder:3:in `block in
>   _b3b681b668d1c2a5691a5b3f7c15bb8e'   /app/views/api/v1/games/game_feed.json.jbuilder:1:in`
>   _b3b681b668d1c2a5691a5b3f7c15bb8e'

But I don't know how to accomplish the fix.  Here are the relevant parts.

**View:**

```
json.game_feed(@game_photos) do |f|
  json.extract! f, :id, :user_id, :username, :image_url_original, :comments_count, :likes_count
  json.comments f.comments do |comment|
    json.(comment, :username, :comment)
  end
  json.likes f.likes do |like|
    json.(like, :id, :user_id, :username)
  end
end
```

**Controller:**

```
@game_photos = CompletedQuest.game_photos(@game.id)
```

**Model:**

```
def self.game_photos(game_id)
  where("completed_quests.game_id = ?", game_id).order("completed_quests.id DESC").just_photos
end

scope :just_photos, -> { where.not( image_file_name: nil ) }
```

**Model relationships:**

```
# CompletedQuests:
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy

# Comments:
belongs_to :completed_quest, counter_cache: true
belongs_to :user
```

So basically for each photo in the feed, it then grabs every comment & likes for ever record - obviously this is bad and I see why, but I can't figure out how to fix it with my current structure.

Any help would be appreciated - but one thing is the structure of the JSON must remain identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [include](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.1/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) the associated `comments` in the query as follows:

```
# app/models/completed_quest.rb
def self.game_photos(game_id)
  includes(:comments).where("completed_quests.game_id = ?", game_id).order("completed_quests.id DESC").just_photos
end
```

This will include all the associated comments in the result, so when you do `f.comments` in your view, there won't be a database query for comments of each `f` instance.

Comment: Thank you so much.. Real quick second issue in the same realm.. `CompletedQuest => [:user] Add to your finder: :include => [:user]` thats another n+1 in my completed_quests, BUT this is the mehtod: `def photo_challenge self.item.photo_challenge end`.  So I can't do it like above b/c theres no where.  Sorry for the comment question!

Comment: @canigetabreak, you don't need `where` to use `includes`.

Comment: How could I add and include to `self.user.username` which is a method in my model to get the username.  I tried but get an `undefined method includes`?

Comment: The `user` association should be eager-loaded automatically as that is an immediate association.  You need not do `includes(:user)`. You could definitely ask another question including the association and the problem.